# How to inject a json config using Helm?

Tags: json, kubernetes, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I have an application which needs to inject various config from GitLab CI/CD variables.

Config is structured like this which is set up as a Gitlab CI/CD variable DEPLOYTIMECONFIG. It needs to be injected at deploy time into the application to a static file, let's say 'deploytimeconfig.json' in the root.

```
{
  "envs": [
    {
      "id": "Dev",
      "enabled": true,
      "name": "Dev",
      "web": {
        "baseUrl": "www.website.com",
        "hhUrlApi": {
          "method": "post",
          "url": "www.website.com"
        }
      },
      "dbs": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "server": "dbserve1r.com",
          "user": "username",
          "password": "pass",
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "server": "dbserver2.com",
          "user": "username",
          "password": "pass",
        }
      ]
    },
   // some others envs
  ]
}
```

I can grab the file in .gitlab-ci.yml by doing:
--set deploytimeconfig={{ DEPLOYTIMECONFIG }} \

And then refer to it in the config map:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: {{ .Values.api.name }}
data:
    deploytimeconfig.json: {{ .Values.deploytimeconfig}}
```

I have tried various methods toJson, toPrettyPrint etc. from the Helm docs, but can't seem to get over the JSON parsing issues or sometimes the file just doesn't end up in the project. Has anyone done something similar and can recommend how I should be approaching this? Does JSON characters need to be escaped or something like this?

Comment: What is the error you're seeing? `--set deploytimeconfig={{ DEPLOYTIMECONFIG }}` in a shell would obviously wreak havoc on your double quotes, I'd recommend single quoting that as first step.

Answer (score 0):

At a Helm template level, the easiest way to get this right is to use YAML block-scalar syntax in combination with Helm's `indent` function.  This will let you inject a multi-line string fairly reliably, without any particular quoting or escaping problems.

```yaml
data:
  deploytimeconfig.json:
{{ .Values.deploytimeconfig | indent 4 }}
```

Note that the `.Values... | indent` line starts at the first column.  The `indent` value is one indentation step more than the previous line.  (Your question uses 4-space indentation, so you'd `indent 8`.)

There's also some question about how the file gets provided.  If your CI system can create the file and put it in the chart source tree, then you can use the [Helm `.Files` object](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/) to retrieve it.  If the file was just dropped in the chart root directory, for example,

```yaml
data:
  deploytimeconfig.json:
{{ .Files.Get "deploytimeconfig.json" | indent 4 }}
```

You also may be able to get your deployment system to write out a Helm values file in either JSON or YAML syntax, with this content as a single quoted or escaped string.  In that case you can use the `.Values` syntax in combination with the `helm install -f` option to provide the additional values file.  If the file is dynamically constructed, this might be a more robust way to inject it.